# Placeholder override with other value - Unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder, html-input

I am setting email field placeholder conditionally using jquery like this

```
$("#UserEmail").attr("placeholder", (auth.currentUser && auth.currentUser.email) || "Email");
```

It works, From devtool i can confirm it. Here is the devtool snapshot
[image: devtool snapshot]

**But the problem is** - in the UI it shows other value. I guess browser override my placeholder from it's cache. Here is the UI snapshot

[image: UI snapshot]

Is there any way to prevent this behavior ?

Comment: why did you write `(auth.currentUser && auth.currentUser.email) || "Email")`

Comment: @Sushil i need to set placeholder with currentUser email address, so that while he is going to update - he can know what his current email address is.

Comment: update your code, I can definitely help you

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the value of **auth.currentUser.email** because It is that value which is getting printed. If it is cache problem then check **Disable Cache** option in network Tab or refresh the browser with **CTRL+F5**.

Comment: Thats not my case, i can delete my browser cache. But what about others(user) ? i need to prevent browser autocomplete functionality.